# How to get unique values in Ansible loop?

Tags: ansible

I need to get a unique UUID value for each item but instead the values are the same.

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{item.uuid}}'

  with_items:
    - uuid: '{{ lookup("pipe", "uuidgen") }}'
    - uuid: '{{ lookup("pipe", "uuidgen") }}'
```

[image]

Comment: You've hit a bug in template cache mechanism. If you provide some context on your actual task/use case, I'll try to advice a workaround.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks. I’m already found a workaround. I added lookup inside my `.j2` file. Maybe do you know how I can get UUID value from template file in my playbook file?

Comment: Have you tried with_together?

Comment: @kalaolani Sorry, I can’t understand how `with_together` can help in this case. Can you show some example?

Comment: I am assuming that you want a different uuid for each target of the play. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, different uuid for each item in the loop